# Choice Site Column set to Checkboxes not displaying in Word Document

Tags: document-library, document, word

I am using SharePoint 2010.

Is it possible to have a Site Column of type Choice, set to be Checkboxes, that I can use in the body of a Word document template via the Quick Parts -> Document Property mechanism so users can fill it out there?

I find that all my other Site Columns display in the choice of Document Properties from the Quick Parts link and I can insert then into my document body that way, but this one does not.

I do see it in the grey Document Properties panel displaying at the top of the document, but I have the kind of users that will be confused by filling in some values there and some in the document body.

I tried this both in my live environment and in a sandbox, no luck. Someone else tried it, too, no luck.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?